# How to display ImageView below TextView in LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm writing a sports app and I want to place the text exactly under the picture, but I can't get it aligned.  If there is a large text somewhere, then the picture is not in the middle.  how to make sure that the text is always exactly under the picture, or the picture is always exactly under the text?

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow_matches_background"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="190dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/title_team_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title_team_1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                    android:text="Chelsea"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title_team_2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                    android:text="Manchester City"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/image_team_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_team_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/title_team_1"
                    android:src="@drawable/image_3" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_team_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/image_5"
                    tools:ignore="DuplicateIds" />


            </RelativeLayout>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date_team_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/image_team_list"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                android:text="25 сентября 2021 года"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/date_team_list">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_subscribe"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#00000000"
                    android:text="@string/btn_subscribe"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorMatchesBtn" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_detail"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#00000000"
                    android:text="@string/btn_detail"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorMatchesBtn" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>


        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00000000">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="190dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="180dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/title_team_list"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        tools:ignore="DuplicateIds">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/title_team_1"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                            android:text="Everton"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            tools:ignore="DuplicateIds" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/title_team_2"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                            android:text="Norvich City"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            tools:ignore="DuplicateIds" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/image_team_list"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/title_team_list"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        tools:ignore="DuplicateIds">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/img_team_1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:src="@drawable/image_3"
                            tools:ignore="DuplicateIds" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/img_team_2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:src="@drawable/image_5"
                            tools:ignore="DuplicateIds" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/date_team_list"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/image_team_list"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                        android:text="25 сентября 2021 года"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        tools:ignore="DuplicateIds" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/date_team_list">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btn_subscribe"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="#00000000"
                            android:text="@string/btn_subscribe"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorMatchesBtn"
                            tools:ignore="DuplicateIds" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btn_detail"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="#00000000"
                            android:text="@string/btn_detail"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorMatchesBtn"
                            tools:ignore="DuplicateIds" />


                    </LinearLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>


            </RelativeLayout>


        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should follow Constraint layout, for your desired output I have attached some code. I hope, it helps.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/ivPic"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/ivPic"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/ivPic"
    android:text="Your desired text"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivPic"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvTitle"
    android:src="@drawable/yourImage"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:padding="2dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvClubName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/ivPic"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/ivPic"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ivPic"
    android:text="Liverpool"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

And take a look at [ConstrainsLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) It will help you out build more complex layouts easily.Also your list of teams is completely hardcoded you should definetely switch to [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview).